# Parsing a variable in JavaScript and performing a regex on it

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables

I'm trying to get a website's HTML code, go through each line and check if it contains a certain pattern, and use a regex on that line to remove the unnecessary things.

I'm wondering how I can achieve this.

Optimal:

Some html-

reading through it and getting a line like this

```
<a href="/player/found">found</a>
```

checking if the line contains a href, and it does!  so we continue with using regex on it

and we are left with `found`

now it continues reading through the lines and looking for another one where it contains a href and uses regex on it-and so on

it doesnt have to be a href it could be anything the proccess is like this:

read line->if in the line there is a certain string->preform command

i need a very universal script,not one build only for a href

please dont use weird JS terms i do not understand... cant anyone understand what i need?

i need to be ablt to get the lines and regexmatch to remove the rest,just teach me that little thing please...

Comment: You can't really reliably parse HTML with regex.

Comment: You can just get all links using `document.anchors`, or even getting them by tag name (even if it is unnecessary, with `document.anchors`) - no need to recreate the wheel there.

Comment: THE A HREF IS AN EXAMPLE!!! it could be anything

Comment: Then you can _still_ just use JS to fetch the DOM nodes you are interested in. You absolutely don't need to regex the HTML to find something of interest to then regex.

Comment: "please dont use weird JS terms i do not understand... cant anyone understand what i need?" Yes, you seem to need the "weird JS terms", as those are how you use JS in the first place. What you are currently asking is "I want to use a screw driver to place some nails in my wall but don't give me any of that 'swing it' or 'pick up a hammer' stuff"

Comment: We understand what you need, we're just afraid you don't really understand the scope of the problem you're trying to approach here. Regular expressions as an approach will fail here, miserably - that's the third lesson of a second year CS computability and complexity class - regular languages. You should consider explaining what you're actually trying to do and not focus on the regular expression part.

Answer (score 1):

```
// First we select all anchor tags <a>
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// We loop through them...
for (var i = 0, max = anchors.length; i < max; i += 1) {
    // ... and replace their innerHTML <a>THIS</a> with whatever.
    // In this example we replace spaces with dashes.
    anchors[i].innerHTML = anchors[i].innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '-');
};
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/hCN7b/

Comment: You realize `anchors` is an array, right? `for ... in ` is typically used for plain objects/non-array objects, because arrays have the `length` property.

Comment: by the way i want the (if the string contains) custom it could be      random something bloop found and then if it cointains the word bloop regex it to give me "found"

Comment: Can I has `document.links` instead and a normal for loop?

Comment: @user3718164 added some comments in the code for you.

Comment: @AlienWebguy good answer, it answers one of my questions too!